# Install pyspark + pytest in docker container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, pytest

I'm trying to unit test my pyspark code using pytest but can't figure out the proper steps and method of installation. I was able to get this working locally on my Mac using this [tutorial](https://maelfabien.github.io/bigdata/SparkInstall/#). I've tried 2 methods to accomplish this:

1. Try to replicate what I did on my Mac in the Dockerfile. i.e. install pypark, apache-spark, java 8, scala, pytest, and make sure I get the ENV paths correct.
2. Use an image from docker like [bitnami](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark).

I attempted (1) but could not find the right `RUN` command to install java properly.

For (2), is there any way in the Dockerfile for me to install bitnami separately from pytest since bitnami does not give root access?

Note:
Bitnami does not put py4j in the PYTHONPATH so I had to add this line to the docker file:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH="${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip:${PYTHONPATH}"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about building your image `FROM bitnami:spark` and adding pytest?

I created `test_spark.py`:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def test1():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    data = spark.sql("SELECT 1").collect()

    assert data == [(1,)]
```

and a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM bitnami/spark:latest

RUN pip install pytest py4j

COPY test_spark.py .

CMD python -m pytest test_spark.py
```

Now I can build and run my container and execute the pytests:

```
docker build . -t pytest_spark && docker run pytest_spark

[+] Building 0.1s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN pip install pytest py4j                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [3/3] COPY test_spark.py .                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:33b5f945afb750aecb0a8e1b2e811eb71b2bb2e67752e1b73a2c321bcc433841                                                             0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/pytest_spark                                                                                                          0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
 08:13:35.34
 08:13:35.34 Welcome to the Bitnami spark container
 08:13:35.35 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
 08:13:35.35 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
 08:13:35.35

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.15, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /opt/bitnami/spark
collected 1 item

test_spark.py .                                                          [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 10.11s ==============================
```